# Can I create a webhook in BigCommerce without using the API?

Tags: bigcommerce, webhooks

I am trying to do a quick integration with a client who is using BigCommerce for their e-commerce platform. She wants the order data from BigCommerce to automatically create resources in our system (customers and orders.)

Ideally, a user of BigCommerce can simply drop our URL into a form and submit it, creating the webhook connection. Unfortunately, all I can find is this documentation showing how to do it as a "Public App" for BigCommerce:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/webhooks-getting-started

Is this the only way? How can I register a new webhook without going through the ceremony of creating a Public App and doing the OAuth dance?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webhooks require an OAuth token which can only be obtained by creating an app. You'll need to follow the steps outlined in the URL you referenced in order to create an app and register webhooks.